# Find the probability of getting one diamond and one spade in a five-card hand, using binomial coefficients.

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

> 5. A five card hand is dealt at random from a standard $52$ card deck. Let $X = \text{# spades}$ and $Y = \text{# diamonds}$. Find $P(X = 1\text{ and }Y =1)$. Leave your answer as a ratio of products of binomial coefficients.

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7OLG.png)

Please help me with this question. I don't know how to apply the binomial coefficient in to this question. My attempt would be:

$ ^{52}C_5 \times^{13}C_1\times^{13}C_1$

But I know for sure that this is not the right answer. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Just as a simple check, notice that the value you have is not a probability. It is greater that 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may assume that the sample space we are working in is the one where order of cards does not matter (*it will not change the final answer compared to if we had decided to work in the space where order does in fact matter*).  Let us count how many hands exist where there is exactly one spade and exactly one diamond.  Approach via multiplication principle:

- Pick the one spade used

> $\binom{13}{1}$ choices

- Pick the one diamond used

> $\binom{13}{1}$ choices

- Pick the remaining three non-spade/non-diamond cards used

> $\binom{26}{3}$ choices

There are then a total of $\underline{~~~~}$ possible hands with exactly one spade and exactly one diamond:

> $\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{26}{3}$

The probability is then the ratio of the number of "good" possibilities to the number of elements in the sample space (*assuming every element in the sample space is equally likely as is the case in this scenario*).

> $\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{26}{3} / \binom{52}{5}$

---

Remember that when using an *equiprobable sample space* $S$, (one in which all outcomes in the sample space are equally likely to occur), for any event $A\subseteq S$ we have $Pr(A) = \frac{|A|}{|S|}$

In our case, the sample space being the set of all possible five card hands from a fifty-two card deck where order doesn't matter, we have $|S|=\binom{52}{5}$

Comment: Could you please explain more when you need to decided by $ ^{52}C_5 $? Thank you!

Comment: @Krin added extra paragraph.  In some naive definitions of probability, you can take $Pr(A)=\frac{|A|}{|S|}$ as a definition (*for equiprobable sample spaces $S$*), but there is justification for this if you use stricter definitions.  (*note: this is outright false in the case that $S$ is not equiprobable*)

Answer (score 4):

There are $\binom{52}{5}$ equally likely $5$-card hands.

Now we count the "favourables," the hands that have precisely $1$ $\spadesuit$ and $1$ $\diamondsuit$.

The $\spadesuit$ can be chosen in $\binom{13}{1}$ ways. For each of these ways, the $\diamondsuit$ can be chosen in $\binom{13}{1}$ ways. And *for each of these ways* the remaining $3$ cards can be chosen from the $26$ $\heartsuit$ and/or $\clubsuit$ in $\binom{26}{3}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{26}{3}$ ways.

Finally, divide by $\binom{52}{5}$ for the probability.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Thanks. It makes a difference in bridge!

Comment: I wish more people (or more accurately *anyone*) in my circle of friends played.  I seem to be the only one.

Comment: @JMoravitz Duplicate Bridge Clubs abound in most places of the world, *even in North America*. Phone your local club and ask if they provide a partnership service.